# typescript: get dictionary in array of dictionaries with highest key value

Tags: typescript

I have an array of dictionaries and I am trying to fetch the dictionary with the highest value from the array.

```
const array = [{"value": 1}, {"value": 3}, {"value": 2}]
```

I want to fetch `{"value": 3}` since its "value" key has the highest value.

What is the most elegant way of achieving this in TypeScript?
I thought about sorting the array first by the value key but even that seems to be a pain.

Comment: 1. "*Why do people like TypeScript so much anyway?*" how is that relevant to the question? 2. How is this a TypeScript question? It'd be the same in JS or TS. Adding types doesn't change the algorithm you want

Comment: @VLAZ I'm sorry if I offended you. What is the Javascript way then? I'm looking for some cool higher order function here

Comment: It's a simple `.reduce()` over the dataset always keeping the higher of the two objects and passing it off to the next iteration. Guaranteed `O(n)` with a single pass.

Comment: @VLAZ very cool! Can you write out the answer in code?

Comment: `array.reduce((highest, current) => current.value > highest.value ? current : highest)`. If you want to make sure it works on empty arrays without throwing an error and without extra checks, you can add an initial value: `{value: -Infinity}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=13&pln=5&pc=20#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDYFcUG8BQyRyAbpjgFzIhYC2ARtANz4C%20%20%20CA9iAM5jI4UKHACeFdNggBtALrIAvMmm5kAIjJS1VAIzJWAGmSqN5CNuQBmfUZOacFnXsPH1981QAMN16a1UADh87M0dvVlkWTh5%20ZF46RUFhMQA6KAgAEywkAAocxAQ6LAw4MC4oKkkcIwgMCFoIcEqzAEpFAD5jQmJgGGR8hELaYtLy6T8HeU7a%20sawcfc1WRbu4mJ0sCwoEEFBopKyqBY1ja2dmYbwFlYWqO4%20LjqUjC4Acxz42lugA)

```
   interface Value {
    value: number;
}

    const array:Value[] = [{ "value": 1 }, { "value": 3 }, { "value": 11 }, { "value": 0 }, { "value": 8 }, { "value": 10 }];
    
    const greatest = array.reduce((accumulator: Value, element: Value) => {
        if (accumulator["value"] > element["value"])
            return accumulator;
        return element;
    });
    
    console.log(greatest);
```

Comment: What if there is a dictionary in the array that does NOT contain the "value" key?

Comment: @etayluz `5 > undefined` is `false`. Same with `undefined > 5`. Here `5` stands for any number.

Comment: You can make it generic but the key should be number because you are comparing them in terms of numeric values